# Mysql Join two Id's to get there Usernames

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to get in Array that contains the results from a MYSQL query.
I have 2 ids stored in the table hitlist user_id and mark_id
they need to join in the table users to retrieve there usernames that match there id's and in the future other variables.

i have this working in a weird way and was hopeing to get this working in a more efficent simple way similar to this

```
$Hitlists = $db->query("SELECT * FROM hitlist JOIN users ON hitlist.user_id = users.id AND hitlist.mark_id = users.id")->fetchAll();
```

This is the code i have that is working...for now it looks like it might give me problems later on.

```
<?php
$index = 0;
$Hitlists = array();
$st = $db->query("SELECT * FROM hitlist JOIN users ON hitlist.user_id = users.id")->fetchAll();
$sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM hitlist JOIN users ON hitlist.mark_id = users.id")->fetchAll();

foreach($st as $id) 
{
    $Hitlists[] = $id;
}

foreach($sth as $id) 
{
        $Hitlists[$index]['markedby'] = $id['username'];
        $Hitlists[$index]['mark_id'] = $id['mark_id'];
        $index++;
}
```

Comment: Do you want combined result or those rows if `mark_id` or `user_id` matches `users.id`?

Comment: it should be combined results to get the username for b. or c. as the answer john woo put below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are joining the table is wrong. You can get the exact records you want, you need to join `users` table twice to get the username of each `ID`

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.username User_name,
        c.username mark_name      
FROM    hitlist a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON  a.user_id = b.id 
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON  a.mark_id = c.id
```

and you can access

```
$result['User_name'] 
$result['mark_name']
```

Comment: Ha ha, I dont know why i wrote that answer

Comment: do you know how i would access b.username and c.username?

Comment: $result = $st->fetchAll();
$b.username = $result['b.username']
$c.username = $result['c.username']

Comment: ah ok, you need to add alias on the column, I will update the answer.